# Returning arrays in methods generates garbage?

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage-collection

I remember reading somewhere that returning arrays in a method generates unnecessary garbage, whereas passing the array as reference does not.

```
//    Bad example. Generates garbage.
public int[] GetIntArray()
{
    int[] intArray = new int[capacity]
    //    Fill the array with something.
    return intArray;
}

//    Good example. No garbage.
public void GetIntArray(int[] intArray)
{
    //    Fill the array with something.
    return;
}
```

Is it true? Should I worry about it and really avoid the first case?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it true?

Not in this particular example.  If you had *passed in* an array and created a *new* array based off of it, then yes, you would have used more memory, but in this case there's just one array - either it's created inside the method or outside of it.

> Should i worry about it and really avoid the first case?

*In general* there is not a hard and fast rule for when to create a new collection and when to modify the existing collection.  There are valid use cases for both, so it depends on the situation as to which method is "better".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It prevents the method from re-using the same array. In general it's more efficient to let the caller perform the memory allocation. However, whether or not this is worth the trouble is obviously a trade-off.

Comment: The same amount of memory is created, regardless of who creates it, at least in the example given.

Comment: @Servy: Did you even *read* my answer? The problem is the **re-use** of the same array, i.e. the **number** of times the memory is reallocated (and zero'd, which also takes time), not *how much* memory is reallocated. I suspect you've never programmed in C or C++? This is standard knowledge in that domain.

Comment: There's no indication that the array is able to be re-used.  It's highly probable that it won't be.

Comment: @Servy: You literally know nothing about the code that the OP wrote --there is literally no code beside allocating and returning a new array. How in the world did you suddenly jump to the conclusion that the array won't be reused?! You also seem to be missing the fact that the whole point is to *allow* it to be re-used, not to *force* it to be re-used -- it's worth making that case possible even if it isn't usual.

Comment: The fact that in extremely rare situations it's *possible* that you could save on allocations, even though there's no indication that the OP is actually in such a situation (nor a description of what such situations are) is *Very* different from saying that, in general, the caller allocating the array is more efficient.  *In general* they're identical.  In extremely rare edge conditions they may not be entirely identical.